Crystal reports, selection criteria is between today and today-7days
would really appreciate some help with the following.
I have 3 sets of data to work with here. Purchase, Stock and Sales.
The report i am working on gathers information about stock available currently and stock due in. That all works perfectly.
Now i need to include sales over the last 7 days.
From ORDRTRXS.REQ_DEL_DATE, is today or within last 7 days i would like to sum the total of WGT_CONFIRMED. The date format seems to be YYYY-MM-DD.
My thought process is to have a second selection criteria with a formula to suit, then summarise the total in each group for the products selected.
Can anyone give me some advise on this as dates is not something i have tried to work with in Crystal before.
Thanks in advance
At first a tried various formula but kept returning errors.

This question may be too broad in focus.  I would recommend beginning with a report that focuses entirely on one of three datasets.  Then include two subreports for each of the remaining datasets.  This will allow unique selection criteria in the subreports without multiple starting points in your report's data.  Then once you have this basic report working, you should be able to ask more specific questions that should be able to get better responses and answers.  Broad questions like this tend to get few answers or vague answers at best, so the more specific you can be, the better.
